# Netbeans crashes while initializing and so does Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Currently running Lubuntu 18.04

Okay so I installed NetBeans and it crashed on startup.  Purged Netbeans and reinstalled it fresh.  It crashed again.  After that I installed eclipse and when I tried to start it I was presented with a directory for an error log:

> !SESSION Fri Oct 19 15:20:48 PDT 2018 !ENTRY
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-10-19 15:20:48.770 !MESSAGE
>   Exception launching the Eclipse Platform: !STACK
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
>           at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

So I'm at a loss I'm pretty sure it has to do with the JRE/JDK versions but I don't even know which version should work with eclipse or netbeans. I really just need an easy way to compile java I'm trying to get this set up for a class I'm taking.

Comment: Which operating system do you have and how are you starting these applications? Also, for an IDE, you need a JDK; a JRE isn't sufficient.

Comment: I was installing and uninstalling the IDE, JDK, and JRE all at the same time with each other.  The JRE, JDK, and IDEs are all installed now but they both crash when i click on their program.desktop files on my desktop.

Comment: These instructions might be useful: [How to Install NetBeans IDE 8.2 in Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-netbeans-ide-8-2-in-ubuntu-18-04/)

Answer (score 0):

[Mick Mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905488/mick-mnemonic)
gave me [this](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-netbeans-ide-8-2-in-ubuntu-18-04/)
link to a decent tutorial on using oracle and netbeans self installer instead of trying to install directly through synaptic package manager or apt-get.